# Anylogic model stop without message

Tags: anylogic

I have created a model to generate a product that will be cycled through a list of machines. Technically the product list is for a single-day run, but I run the model for long durations to stabilise the model output.

The model can run properly for months until around 20 months, then suddenly stops without any error message as shown in the screenshot. I do not know how to debug this since I do not know where the error comes from.

Does anyone have a similar encounter and could advise on how to approach this issue? Could it be an issue of memory overload?

[image: Model stop without error message]

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, it's hard to pinpoint the exact reason, but this generally happens if the run is stuck in an infinite While Loop or similar. So check all your loops where it's possible for such a scenario to happen and it's likely that one of them (or more) is causing the issue.